# Cleaning up javascript repetition

Tags: javascript

I am a newby at javascript and am trying to find a way to condensed the javascript code below to something more manageable. There are some areas where the code is repeated and I would like a way to clean it up. As you can see there are some parameters that are repeated and I'd like to only use these once.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#barcelona').on('click', function() {     
        $(this).lightGallery({
        //--START OF REPEATED CODE FOR EACH
        mode: 'lg-zoom-in',
        cssEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000)',
        speed: 500,
        dynamic: true,
        hideBarsDelay: 2000,
        thumbnail: true,
        //--END OF REPEATED CODE FOR EACH
            dynamicEl: [{
                "src": '../img/barcelona01.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/barcelona01_thb.jpg',
            }, {
                "src": '../img/barcelona02.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/barcelona02_thb.jpg',
            }, {
                "src": '../img/barcelona03.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/barcelona03_thb.jpg',
            }]
        })
     
    });
    
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#london').on('click', function() {     
        $(this).lightGallery({
        mode: 'lg-zoom-in',
        cssEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000)',
        speed: 500,
        dynamic: true,
        hideBarsDelay: 2000,
        thumbnail: true,
            dynamicEl: [{
                "src": '../img/london01.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/london01_thb.jpg',
            }, {
                "src": '../img/london02.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/london02_thb.jpg',
            }, {
                "src": '../img/london03.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/london03_thb.jpg',
            }]
        })
     
    });
    
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rome').on('click', function() {     
        $(this).lightGallery({
        mode: 'lg-zoom-in',
        cssEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000)',
        speed: 500,
        dynamic: true,
        hideBarsDelay: 2000,
        thumbnail: true,
            dynamicEl: [{
                "src": '../img/rome01.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/rome01_thb.jpg',
            }, {
                "src": '../img/rome02.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/rome02_thb.jpg',
            }, {
                "src": '../img/rome03.jpg',
                'thumb': '../img/rome03_thb.jpg',
            }]
        })
     
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show what you have done to avoid this repetitive code and what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function called `options` that will return necessary object and pass a parameter `city` for image sources and thumbnails.

```
const options = (city) => {
  return {
  mode: 'lg-zoom-in',
        cssEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000)',
        speed: 500,
        dynamic: true,
        hideBarsDelay: 2000,
        thumbnail: true,
            dynamicEl: [{
                "src": `../img/${city}01.jpg`,
                'thumb': `../img/${city}01_thb.jpg`,
            }, {
                "src": `../img/${city}02.jpg`,
                'thumb': `../img/${city}rome02_thb.jpg`,
            }, {
                "src": `../img/${city}03.jpg`,
                'thumb': `../img/${city}.jpg`,
            }]
        }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rome').on('click', function() {     
        $(this).lightGallery(options('rome'))     
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a starting point for me but I think I forgot to mention another aspect of what I am looking for. I would prefer for the dynamicEl parameter to be separate from the others because it may be of various amounts of image files and also the naming convention might also vary. I'm sorry I should have mentioned this at the start.